# How can I display an HTML snippet on an HTML page?

Tags: html, tags, quote

I want my project to display `<div>` quoted on the website. I am using the `<code>` tag. However, it doesn't appear. This is the piece of code I am using:

```
<div class="section">
    <h3>Additional Style</h3>
    <h2>Box Model of <code><div></code>
    <!--
    I want this code to output the following: Box Model of <div>

    However, it outputs: Box Model of

    -->
    </h2>
    <ul>
        <li>padding: 40px,</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: a `<h2>` tag is a higher level than a `<h3>`. You should keep them in structural order (and never use them for styling purposes).

Comment: Who approved the conversion into broken English (revision 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of code.

Source: *[HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)*

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `<h2>Box Model of &ltdiv&gt`

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is the idea? What is the thinking behind it? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60582230/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).